# What is this small, evergreen perennial in zone 6b?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials, shade

This is 2 stems, each with 3 leaves.  The leaves are thick and stiff with serrated edges.  The leaf is about 2".  The whole thing is about 2" high.  A few of these have popped up in the garden. This one has been here for about 3 years and has only grown this big.  I'm in zone 6b in Pennsylvania.  In the woods.  I have not seen anything around that looks anything like this.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: That little thing is 3 yrs. old? ... Well we know it can't be a weed. (just kidding)

Comment: Do the others that have popped up have the same configuration of 2 stems and 3 leaves on each stem? Are they 5he same size as this 3 year old one?

Comment: Looks rather like a Hellebore seedling to me, but I can't think of any plant that would just look like this for three whole years, without increasing growth, losing its leaves or flowering

Comment: I have to agree with you about being a helebore. I also don't understand why it isn't growing.  I went out to look at it again today and it's probably 3" off the ground.  The others are the same, one stem and 3 leaves but tiny.  I have babies under the mother plant that have grown so much in 2 years and they look just like a full grown hellebore.  I looked under the mother plant and to my surprise I did see a tiny 3 leafed one so I'm betting you ar right.  Thank you so much for your help. You led me in the right direction.

Comment: I've grown many plants from seed, some just for fun like citrus seeds. Every now and then, a plant will develop two true leaves; not cotyledon (seed leaves) but not grow any further. When I've checked, there is nothing - no tiny growing point - between the two stems that show a new branching stem developing. So now and then a dud grows that stays like that. I've kept some for months to see if anything happens. It doesn't but the tiny plant doesn't die either. Perhaps that's what the 3 year old is.

Comment: Wow, very interesting. Thanks a lot. I'll leave it there until I'm sick of looking at it.....or it does something. LOL

Answer (score 2):

That's a young [helleborus (Lenten Rose)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellebore). If the conditions are off, they can take a very long time to settle in. Probably a seedling. In zone 6b PA, they are evergreen and old leaves don't die back until new ones have formed. If you want to grow them, transplant to a shady, well drained spot with high organic matter levels, and keep it watered. They are nitrogen suckers but too much can cause them to lodge.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. It's in partial shade but I'll move it to all shade. I appreciate your answer.